# Generator Matrix from a Parity check matrix

Tags: coding-theory

My task is to use syndromes to decode few words to their unique nearest neighbour
in C under IMLD.

I got my parity check matrix given which is equal
$ H = \begin{bmatrix}
       X \\
       I_{7}
     \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
 1& 1 & 0 &0  &0  &1  &1 \\ 
 0& 1 & 1 &0  & 1 & 1 & 0\\ 
 1&0  &0  &0  &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 &  0& 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 &  0& 0 & 1 & 0 &0 \\ 
 0& 0 &  0& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
 0& 0 &  0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

To obtain the cosets and syndromes I need to get my Generator Matrix

Is it correct to get the Generator Matrix from Transformation matrix in the following steps:

1) Transpose H

2) Transofm it further to $RREF$

3) Remove the leading columns ?

Comment: The relation between generator matrices and parity check matrices is discussed in [for example this questio](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/279697/11619). You will find that some authors denote by $H^T$ what the author of your textbook denotes $H$. Get used to it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the Generator Matrix to decode to any codeword. What you can do is the following. The syndrome vector $s=r*H$ where $r$ is a received $1\mathrm{X}N$ vector. The syndrome can be identified also as follows: Let the received vector be $r=c_{t}+e$ where $c_{t}$ is the transmitted codeword and $e$ is the error vector that corrupted the codeword. We all know that the Parity check matrix is the null space for the codewords. Now then $s = e*H$ and you have the position of the codeword which had an error in it. Say if $s=e*H$ picked up the 3rd column of $H^{T}$, then the 3rd bit was erreneous in the received vector $r$.

Comment: Thank You! It helped a lot + i've found extra material in my book which a bit explained it to me (I feel a bity dizzy after whole day at the computer reading and trying to solve those tasks:). If I understood correctly: the word $10100011111$ after multiplication with $ H^T $ gave the result $ 0000100 $ so it picked up the 9th column of $ H^T $ and the error is on the 9th bit? From other codeword I received the syndrome $1110111$, but I am to correct errors with weight at least 2, and this syndrome looks like a sum of few columns and I assume the answer for this should be just *?

Comment: I'm sorry my bad. The above explanation is applicable to a Hamming code that is always single error correcting. For your case, in case you need the Generator Matrix to write down the Syndrome table, it is simple. Since $H^{T}G=0$ (keeping in mind your notation), if $H^{T}=[X^{T}|I]$, then G is simply $[I|X^{T}]$.

Comment: And the first method that I described corrects all single errors and for Hamming codes the Minimum distance is bounded by 4. It can never correct double errors according to the Singleton Bound. I don't know what code is your Parity Check Matrix from; it certainly has a Singleton Bound of 5. Now you need to get the Generator Matrix to write the Syndrome table.

Comment: I think i got it anyway without the generation matrix. In the book  "Coding theory and cryptography the essentials" at the error patter and syndrome are written in following way from a parity-check matrix (6x3) (ep:synd): 100000: row1; 010000: row2 etc + all codewords from $K^3$ in syndrome. Luckily the syndromes that came out in my task where not any difficult combinations. syndromes are 0000100 (which is row 7 in H) and 1110111 (row 1 + 2 in H). so went quite easy! errors at place 7 and next one at 1st and 2nd place! thank You anyways, helped a lot!

Comment: PS. How have you verified that singleton bound of the code with this parity check matrix is 5? It is also a part of my task :-) - ok easy!:) distance is d-1 where d is the number of linearly independant rows in at least one set (i assume the biggest possible)?

Comment: Singleton bound:

The Minimum Distance of any code with blocklength $n$ and information symbol length $k$ is $d_{min}\leq n-k+1$. Our parity check matrix is $11 \mathrm{X} 7$ and so $n=11,k=7$ which leads to the conclusion that $d_{min}$ cannot be greater than $5$. If $d_{min}$ was 5 then you can correct 2 errors or else you can never correct 2 errors. $d_{min}$ can actually be found out as the least number of Rows (generally columns, since H will be written as a wide matrix but you've written it as tall) of a Parity Check Matrix that are dependent. You can verify that if you want to.

Comment: Also for a good detailed discussion on Block Codes, I'd always recommend that you refer to "Algebraic Codes for Data Transmission" by Richard E. Blahut.